# IValueConverter resource, namespace issue

Tags: c#, namespaces, windows-phone-8, ivalueconverter

I try to implement IValueConverter  class and map it as resource in xaml file. In some reason im allways getting error "The name TypeConverter does not exist in the namespace clr-namespace:MyApp"

But I can not find whats the issue there, my converter class has namespace correctly set etc..

My xml file

```xml
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="MyApp.Page"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

...

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding items}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

    <ListBox.Resources>
        <local:TypeConverter x:Name="TypeConverter"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>

    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding type, Converter={StaticResource TypeConverter}}"  Margin="0,0,12,0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

My converter class

```cs
namespace MyApp
{
    public class TypeConverter: IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, String culture)
        {
            return "-";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, String culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error comes up in designer or at compile time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue myself, convert method has wrong parameters, needs to be:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
```

When fixed this, compiler (and) designer does not give namespace error any more.